# Solution to the 2nd Order ODE using Variation of Parameters

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm trying to find the solution to:

$$ a_n''(t) +n^2c^2a_n(t) = q_n(t) = \frac{2(-1)^{n+1}w^2A}{n\pi}sin(\omega t) $$ subject to 
$$ a_n(0) = 0 \ \ a'_n(0) = \frac{2(-1)^{n+1}wA}{n\pi} $$.

---

It's easy to see the general solution is $$a_n(t) = \frac{2\omega A}{n^c\pi}(-1)^{n+1}sin(nct)$$

but I'm having issues finding the particular solution.

I've tried the following:

$$a_{n_{p}}(t) = A(t)cos(nct) + B(t)sin(nct) $$ where 
$$ A(t) = -\int \frac{q_n(t)sin(nct)}{nc}dt $$ and 
$$ B(t) = \int\frac{q_m(t)cos(nct)}{nc}dt$$ where $nc$ is the Wronskian of $sin(nct), \ \ cos(nct)$

Comment: Try a solution for the form $a(t) = A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t$

Comment: For the particular solution?

Comment: Yes. From your edit it seems you have attempted variation of parameters? There is a simpler method for autonomous equations such as this. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a particular solution of the form $a_{n_p}(t) = A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t$; plugging that into the equation

$$ a_{n_p}'' + (nc)^2 a_{n_p} = C_n\sin\omega t $$

$$ C_n = \frac{2(-1)^{n+1}\omega ^2A}{n\pi} $$

yields

$$ (-\omega^2 + (nc)^2)(A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t) = C_n\sin\omega t $$

Matching the coefficients of the sines and cosines yields

$$
A = 0
\qquad
B = \frac{C_n}{-\omega^2+(nc)^2}
$$

This heuristic for finding particular solutions for linear autonomous equations when the source term is a sum of functions of the form $e^{-st}t^n$ is called the method of [undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, its clear now. I have the doubt here:                           How come that the solutions are equivalent in this case? My solution comes up with terms in both $sin(\omega t), \ cos(\omega t)$ Also, wouldn't there be an issue in $\omega = nc$, that is, $\omega$ is a solution of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: The difference between the two particular solutions is probably just a homogeneous solution and then both are equally valid. If we fix boundary conditions, then the solutions should coincide

Comment: Regarding "wouldn't there be an issue with $\omega = nc$": Well observed... yes, there would; in that case the the form of the solution will be different. In the Wikipedia article I mentioned there should be mention of that.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I'll take some time to read it!